# CKEditor and file upload through the default file manager (filebrowserUploadUrl)

Tags: ckeditor, image-uploading

I've configured CKEditor so that it supports file upload by using the image toolbar button (configured the server upload through the filebrowserUploadUrl) or by using drag and drop. Now, I need to intercept the ajax request for the update so that I can add more info to the object that gets submitted. In the drag-n.drop scenario, there's an event (fileUploadRequest) which I can use to achieve this:

```
editor.on( 'fileUploadRequest', function( evt ) {
    var requestData = evt.data.requestData;
    requestData["__RequestVerificationToken"] = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value;
} );
```

Now, is there anything similar for the image button?

thanks.

Luis

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind. the controller already does that because through the ckCsrfToken cookie.